# Insert 3 forms in framework unknow

Tags: java, jsp

I was assigned the job of adding 3 forms in JAVA with Angular on Tomcat, in a framework of which I do not have manuals.

I have the source code working in eclipse, and I need to insert 3 forms to upload files to the database, in three links that are managed from the database, the links are already working, but not the forms, I tried to replicate other similar class, but not achievement load the data.

I'm thinking of making the forms separately, grabbing other tools that allow opening a new window and processing the data. My problem is what tools can I use to work on tomcat?

I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest test one form first, make sure that your servlets are working for processing the request. You can also try to listen on your servlet is receiving the request.

Just make sure that in angular that they are firing when you hit that submit button.

I just provided here the part where in angular you would check. then just search on how the multi-part (file upload) works.

```
     var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
     app.controller('FormCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {

     var formData = {
        firstname: "default",
        emailaddress: "default",
        ...

    };

    $scope.save = function() {
        formData = $scope.form;
    };

    $scope.submitForm = function() {
        formData = $scope.form;            
    };

 });
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Truth, the framework is on jsf, so you can use that to my advantage and I will continue investigating

Comment: It is better to look first on redered jsf, see how it looks like then debug from there on your browser, then modify your jsf template.